# Extract first N columns of Q from `ColPivHouseholderQR`

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

I am trying to implement canonical correlation analysis in C++ using the `Eigen` linear algebra library.

Part of the algorithm involves QR decomposition using the column pivot method. For that piece I am using the `ColPivHouseholderQR` class. This class contains an object of type `HouseholderSequenceType` which I would like to use to extract only the first N columns of the matrix rather than the entire Q matrix.

The full Q matrix has as many columns as rows and quickly fills memory for even modest dataset sizes. Furthermore, I don't need the full matrix, but just a subset of the first N columns.

How can I extract only the first N columns from this object?

My code:

```
// Set up the class and compute the QR decomposition
Eigen::ColPivHouseholderQR< Eigen::MatrixXd > qr;
qr.setThreshold(threshold);
qr.compute(mat);

int rk = qr.rank();


Eigen::ColPivHouseholderQR< Eigen::MatrixXd >::HouseholderSequenceType  seq = qr.householderQ();
seq.setLength(rk);

// return the matrix
return (Eigen::MatrixXd) seq;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thin QR decomposition in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971989/thin-qr-decomposition-in-c)

Comment: You are correct. That's the answer I need.